# Can IDEA insert the parameter names when choose a method from assistance list?

Tags: intellij-idea

When choose a method from the assistance list, IDEA only insert the method name:

[image]

It will only insert the method name `substring` from the list.

But I want IDEA to insert `beginIndex` and `endIndex` as well, like:

[image]

I remember eclipse has this function, but can't find the same on IDEA. Is it possible on IDEA?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no such functionality. You can [suggest new feature](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/) to JetBrains if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think for now it isn't possible, but those are tips that may help a bit:

- when inside parentheses after method name, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to display a hint with parameter types list
- when assistance list is displayed, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to display a popup with method definition (i.e result type, function name and parameter **types and names**)